# Guideline regarding abbreviations

Tags: discussion, formatting

On Space Exploration we had a discussion before about the use of the abbreviations.

Over there we decided to make our guideline: write things out in full the first time (with abbreviations in parentheses) then use abbreviations later.

What is our stance on abbreviations here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that we use the same guideline as Space Exploration:

**Use the full terminology  the first time, with the abbreviation in parentheses, then use abbreviations later.**

Tags in general should avoid abbreviations except in cases where they are abundantly clear.

Comment: Writing style will be tricky to enforce, but as long as writers try to be informative for as many readers as possible, that should suffice. So some will reverse this and use abbreviation / acronym first and explain its meaning in parentheses, or others will just attach a link to them where it should be more obvious what they meant, et cetera. But of course, I wholeheartedly support this notion and hope as many read it as possible. ;)

Comment: This also works nicely as a guide for editors, not as a main reason to edit, but as something else that can be done if spotted alongside the main edit reason